# Create a new table with 1000+ columns with incrementing names inside sql database

Tags: mysql, database-design, dynamic-sql, ddl

In setting up a new table in a database, how would you create a new table with thousands of columns, each named with a number one larger than the previous?

I.e. [image: example table]

Comment: Which dbms product are you using?

Comment: I'm using mysql

Comment: You would not do that since it would be an abuse of your database. You should redesign your data model.

Comment: The intent is to track whether thousands of items are "completed or incompleted" using a tinyint 0/1

Comment: This is a really bad design. Rather than having thousands of columns, you should create a table with a single column and thousands of rows. Please read up on database normalization.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  A table with one *row* per boolean item.  If in your proposed design there was to be only one "row", then this is straightforward and probably the best.  If you were to have multiple rows (each with thousands of columns), then the table would need to have 3 columns:  the old 'row', the number (up to thousands), and TINYINT with 0/1.

Plan B:  If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can have a single `BLOB` column and set/clear bits in it.

Plan C:  Before 8.0 such an approach was limited to 64 booleans at a time -- either in `BIGINT` or `SET`.  Your "thousands" could be spread across "dozens" of columns (or rows).